# Several replicas into docker swarm

Tags: docker, docker-swarm

Trying to deploy container into swarm. Exec command:

```
 docker service create --name backend --replicas 3 --publish published=8080,target=80 my-repo/subserver:latest
```

It starts 3 replicas, but one of them has errors always:

```
docker service ps --no-trunc backend

    ID                          NAME                   IMAGE                            NODE                          DESIRED STATE       CURRENT STATE                  ERROR                                                 PORTS
0759ox8aganle2banj4s1uc31   backend.1       my-repo/subserver:latest   Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal   Running             Running 2 minutes ago
zjm9tf5ca1t58iuyjsyjqpjnq   backend.2       my-repo/subserver:latest   Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal   Running             Running 2 minutes ago
u9ebicuyh0it6kvpaj9n7id2b   backend.3       my-repo/subserver:latest   Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal   Ready               Ready less than a second ago
4kgwlm4rddj7zefr9tc1xst75    \_ backend.3   my-repo/subserver:latest   Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal   Shutdown            Failed 2 seconds ago           "starting container failed: Address already in use"
dqvsyy5cjd95iid845ylrpdzi    \_ backend.3   my-repo/subserver:latest   Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal   Shutdown            Failed 8 seconds ago           "starting container failed: Address already in use"
ki0y94msyswqirm03qr7ldzl6    \_ backend.3   my-repo/subserver:latest   Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal   Shutdown            Failed 13 seconds ago          "starting container failed: Address already in use"
emydpjqzzo5ce2ngid9ap9pb7    \_ backend.3   my-repo/subserver:latest   Debian-70-wheezy-64-minimal   Shutdown            Failed 19 seconds ago          "starting container failed: Address already in use"
```

Tryed different ports.
Container contains PHP-FPM and nginx. Services start with bash script:

```
#!/bin/bash

service nginx start
service php7.0-fpm start

while /bin/true; do
  ps aux |grep nginx |grep -q -v grep
  PROCESS_1_STATUS=$?
  ps aux |grep php |grep -q -v grep
  PROCESS_2_STATUS=$?
  # If the greps above find anything, they will exit with 0 status
  # If they are not both 0, then something is wrong
  if [ $PROCESS_1_STATUS -ne 0 -o $PROCESS_2_STATUS -ne 0 ]; then
    echo "One of the processes has already exited."
    exit -1
  fi
  sleep 60
done
```

Docker files exposes just 80 port.

Comment: Can you check the list of network interfaces/addresses on the relevant node? (`$ ip address`). Compare with addresses assigned to containers (`docker container inspect ...`).

Answer (score 2):

What's happening here is that you are attempting to create multiple services that are all attaching to the same port. Only a single service can ever attach to any one port - That's not Docker specific and you'll run into this in future tech endeavors as well.

However; what's curious is that by default Swarm mode is that the `ingress` network is [set as the default network](https://docs.docker.com/engine/swarm/networking/) - this is an overlay network with routing-mesh; what's happening under the hood is actually Layer-3 IP load balancing that Docker is handling for you.

So it's curious that you're running into this issue - I would gander to say that you are running an older version of Docker.

If you want to solve this on your own - the simplest way is to create an **overlay** network, eg:

```
docker network create --driver overlay my_new_network
```

And then when creating your service, ensure you specify the network:

```
docker service create --network my_new_network --name backend --replicas 3 --publish published=8080,target=80 my-repo/subserver:latest
```

This will solve the IP-based routing; however if you want to do some Host-based routing, you could do as @Markus stated and use a Layer-7 load balancer like Traefik, Docker Flow Proxy, HAProxy, etc.

Answer (score 1):

When using scaling in swarm mode, don't publish the ports. You will only run in trouble with that.
The correct way is:

1. create a docker network
2. assign your service to this network (don't publish ports)
3. use a reverse proxy (e.g. nginx, apache or traefik) in gobal mode to make your service public on port 80

So your reverse proxy will just call the name of your service (`--name your_service`), and internaly docker swarm mode will use its included round robin load balancer to call one of your n'th service (`--replicas n`)

That's the way docker swarm mode is designed and scaling works out of the box with load balancing.

Comment: Almost. The docker network must be overlay, and you still want to publish ports even if joining a network. Also - the `ingress` network is the default in a swarm configuration and it should work out of the box anyhow. I'm assuming OP is on an older Docker version.